# Using a library on another docker container in the same network

Tags: docker, api, go

I am trying to run the [QR code generator library](https://github.com/skip2/go-qrcode) using [this image](https://hub.docker.com/r/zetaron/docker-qrcode-generator) on my container. I have another container running a web API in the same network and I want to access the QR code library on it. If I had installed the library on the same container as my web app, I can do this to access it from my code:

```golang
import qrcode "github.com/skip2/go-qrcode"
var png []byte
png, err := qrcode.Encode("https://example.org", qrcode.Medium, 256)
```

How do I access the library if it is on a different container?

Comment: Quick question: why don't you install the library in both containers?

Comment: You don't; you wouldn't be able to directly call the library function if it was in a different process, or on a different host, and "a different container" is very similar to both.

Comment: @brandizzi We want the library to be available to other containers in the network as well. Right now I have a web API in container A and the library in container B. Tomorrow if I add another app in container C that wants to user the library, they should be able to do so.

Comment: @DavidMaze you're saying the only way to access it then would be if the library exposed some kind of endpoint for using it?

Comment: Libraries are intrinsically local to the process they're running in, so yes.  Put aside Docker: if you wrote two separate Go programs, and compiled the library into one of them, how would you call the library from the other program?

Comment: @DavidMaze Hmm, makes sense. Thanks!